# How to approach this problem on polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $f(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients and $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $g=f+f'+f''+\cdots$. Prove that $g(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I have not got the proper way to proceed

Comment: It seems the leading order of the polynomial must be even, which you may be able to use in your proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $g-g'=f$ and thus $g(x)\ge g'(x)$ for all $x$ and, in particular, $g'(x)$ is negative as soon as $g(x)$ is. Assume as a contradiction that $g(x_0)<0$. Then, $g(x)<0$ for all $x>x_0$. In fact, if this were not the case, then consider $S=\{y\ge x_0\,:\, g(y)\ge 0\}$ and $\alpha=\inf S$. By continuity, $\alpha\in S$ and so $g(\alpha)\ge 0$. By Lagrange, there is some $\xi\in (x_0,\alpha)$ such that $$\frac{g(\alpha)-g(x_0)}{\alpha-x_0}=g'(\xi)>0$$

But then $g(\xi)\ge g'(\xi)\ge 0$, which is not consistent with the fact that $x_0\le \xi<\inf S$.

So, if there is some $x_0$ such that $g(x_0)<0$, then $g(x)<0$ for all $x\ge x_0$. Therefore, the leading coefficient of $g$ must be negative. However, this is not consistent with the hypothesis that $f$ and $g$ have the same leading coefficient.

So $g(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$.